# Cannot open deployed Heroku App, getting status 137 and App crashed with code=h10

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I created a fullstack app with create-react-app and nodeJS/express, using mongoDB. The app works fine in development, but after successfully building and deploying it with heroku, trying to open the app causes the following error message:

2022-07-04T14:40:00.876477+00:00 app[web.1]: [33m[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json[39m
2022-07-04T14:40:00.876761+00:00 app[web.1]: [32m[nodemon] starting `node index.js`[39m
2022-07-04T14:40:31.255026+00:00 app[web.1]: connection  to 34.233.234.200:27017 closed
2022-07-04T14:40:31.783355+00:00 app[web.1]: [32m[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart[39m
2022-07-04T14:40:59.210171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-04T14:40:59.266895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-04T14:40:59.453613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-07-04T14:40:59.506533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-04T14:41:00.871320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tourney-dpocsai.herokuapp.com request_id=2f82a5f6-e99f-48f6-8da2-f0b27f140486 fwd="99.247.92.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-04T14:41:01.208673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tourney-dpocsai.herokuapp.com request_id=d8a9b491-35c3-415e-8517-3f296c54feea fwd="99.247.92.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

my Procfile has one line: web: npm run start

I am using const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

I am totally lost as to what I could do to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated.